# Is there anyway (built-in / custom write) to show confirmation dialog before inline edit in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, frontend, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My web application currently uses Kendo UI (Grid). I received a requirement to show confirmation dialog before actual entering inline edit mode. I found the library already supports for Delete function, as demonstrated below:

[Show confirmation dialog in Kendo UI Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7pME.png)

But I could not find the same thing for Edit function. Is there anyone know or can suggest a possible way to achieve this?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Add some code or ui .

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the grid options:

```
edit: function(e) {
    if (!confirm("Edit line?")) {
        e.sender.cancelRow();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Turns out the above solution doesn't work with older versions of Kendo UI, specifically version 2014.1.528. There is a way to bypass this issue by using setTimeout:

```
edit: function(e) {
    if (!confirm("Edit row?")) {
        setTimeout(function() { e.sender.cancelRow(); }, 0);
    }
}
```

This way the `cancelRow()` function is run after all the grid's `edit` event is over and so there is no conflict.

Comment: I think it's the right answer :), thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hi @shai, thanks your suggestion to try. It sounds reasonable but it does not work in my case. I posted solution and explanation for my case below in case you want to refer :). Again, thank you so much.

Comment: I tested it in version 2017.1.118 where it works without errors, didn't know you used  an older Kendo version...
I get an exception with version 2014.1.528 too.
Is it possible for you to upgrade to version 2017.1.118?

Comment: Added another solution for older versions of Kendo UI.

Comment: Great. Thanks @Shai :)

Comment: Did you use this solution? Does it suit you? Or did you keep your own solution?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6441048/shai

Thanks your suggestion to try. It sounds reasonable. However, when I applied it I got an exception saying something is null within **editRow** process, like this:

[image]

I did try to investigate what happened, and it turns out the error throws inside Kendo library. I currently have Kendo version 2014.1.528. Digg into the library code and read related flows, I seem understand the way they are designed:

- When we click Edit on a grid’s row, Kendo will call **editRow** method, with purpose to change the grid row to edit mode. Also in this transform, an editor object is created and bound with a cancel event
- When we click Cancel on that row, the cancel event of the created editor is triggered. Inside that event handler, **cancelRow** is called.

[image]

I tracked what **cancelRow** does and see it destroys the editor.

[image]

The object is raised null in my case is detected the editor. So *just my guess here*, **because the cancelRow is called when the editRow flow has not finished yet and it deletes the editor object**, then somehow the flow dispatches the handle to the bound cancel event of the editor, but the editor is already null therefore it throws exception.

To resolve my original problem, I need to try another way, is to add **onClick** event handler for **Edit button** and show my confirmation dialog there. If answer is no, I also need to call **stopPropagation** to prevent the flow entering Kendo library’s editing pipeline.

Comment: Added a solution for older versions to my answer. See if you prefer it over your current solution.